# "Cannot resolve symbol 'TAG'" in Android using code from Google

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on my FIRST APP and using Android Studio for the FIRST TIME (bear that in mind before you vote my question down out of sheer arrogance).

The app utilizes the camera and I've borrowed bits of code from Google to achieve this. However, I am getting an error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'TAG'". Why is this? How do I fix it?

The code snippets include...

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

...and...

```
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where `TAG` is declared and assigned a value?

Comment: I believe it is from `import android.util.Log;` Am I correct? Beyond that, I don't see any declarations in the code. Again, this is code I grabbed from a Google tutorial.

Comment: As [this mentions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html), you still need to declare and assign a value to the `TAG` variable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its just a string used as a tag when printing log messages to the console (ddms).

Add the following line to the **top** of your class:

```
public static final String TAG = "YOUR-TAG-NAME";
```

Comment: +1, although you'd want to change the case of `public` (and I'd personally use `private` instead).